# Query inserts more rows than expected (four instead of one)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Its a simple an obvious error but i can´t find the solution

i have this query :

```sql
INSERT INTO Movimiento (ExpedienteId,FechaIngreso,SectorOrigen,SectorDestino,FechaEnvio) 
SELECT 25,'2022-11-15 00:00:00.000',2,3,'2022-11-19 00:00:00.000' 
FROM Expediente e 
 left JOIN Movimiento m 
  ON e.ExpedienteId = m.ExpedienteId 
WHERE m.ExpedienteId IS NULL
```

The query must insert ONE row in Movimiento but, instead insert the same 4 rows

```sql
select * from Movimiento where ExpedienteId = 25
```

and the result:

```
MovimientoId    ExpedienteId    FechaIngreso    SectorOrigen    SectorDestino   FechaEnvio   
1271    25  2022-11-15 00:00:00.000 2   3   2022-11-19 00:00:00.000    
1272    25  2022-11-15 00:00:00.000 2   3   2022-11-19 00:00:00.000  
1273    25  2022-11-15 00:00:00.000 2   3   2022-11-19 00:00:00.000  
1274    25  2022-11-15 00:00:00.000 2   3   2022-11-19 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Why are you selecting/joining if you are inserting constant values?

Comment: you have 4 rows that are null, because Movimiento  has now corresponding in Expediente  so you get 4 identical rows, but why do you want a table join  or a table for that matter for one constant row?

Answer (score 1):

For each row returned by the query, you are inserting the same constant values. There are 4 entries in `Expediente` without a match in `Movimiento` so the constants are inserted 4 times.

You can just do

```
INSERT INTO Movimiento (ExpedienteId,FechaIngreso,SectorOrigen,SectorDestino,FechaEnvio) 
SELECT 25,'2022-11-15 00:00:00.000',2,3,'2022-11-19 00:00:00.000'
```

If the goal is to insert the "missing" entries, don't use the constant `25` but rather `e.ExpedienteId`

```sql
INSERT INTO Movimiento (ExpedienteId,FechaIngreso,SectorOrigen,SectorDestino,FechaEnvio) 
SELECT e.ExpedienteId,'2022-11-15 00:00:00.000',2,3,'2022-11-19 00:00:00.000' 
FROM Expediente e 
 left JOIN Movimiento m 
  ON e.ExpedienteId = m.ExpedienteId 
WHERE m.ExpedienteId IS NULL
```

Comment: The idea is .. i have a single row in Expediente (id 25) , so i want one insert row into  movimiento with id = 25 (because they al correlated) .. thanks for the help by the way